# angular dynamic forms add nested form arrays

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I am trying to create a dynamic form where you can add forms dynamically, and sub forms dynamically. For example:

```
+ user1  
--- + color1  
--- + color2  
--- + color3  
+ user2  
--- + color1  
--- + color2  
--- + color3  
+ user 3  
--- + color1
```

Where as you can add as many users as you want, and you can add as many colors as you want to each user. I can get the first array to work (users), but not sure about the nested array (colors). I have it set up so it loads a user and a color at the beginning. Here is my code I have so far:

```
export class FormsComponent implements OnInit {

  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      email: '',
      users: this.fb.array([])
    })
  }

  get userForms() {
    return this.myForm.get('users') as FormArray
  }

  get colorForms() {
    return this.userForms.get('colors') as FormArray
  }

  addUser() {
    const userGroup = this.fb.group({
      user: [],
      colors: this.fb.array([])
    })
    this.userForms.push(userGroup);
  }

  deleteUser(i) {
    this.userForms.removeAt(i);
  }

  addColor() {
    const colorGroup = this.fb.group({
      color: []
    })
    this.colorForms.push(colorGroup);
  }

  deleteColor(i) {
    this.colorForms.removeAt(i)
  }

}
```

And this is my html code:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">

  <hr>

  <input formControlName="email">

  <div formArrayName="users">

    <div *ngFor="let user of userForms.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">

      <input formControlName="user">

      <button (click)="deleteUser(i)">Delete User</button>

      <div formArrayName="colors">

        <div *ngFor="let color of colorForms.controls; let t=index" [formGroupName]="t">

          <input formControlName="color">

          <button (click)="deleteColor(t)">Delete Color</button>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <button (click)="addUser()">Add User</button>

</form>
```

Obviously this doesn't work, so I am trying to comprehend what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you do not take into account the index in which controls are stored.

For example

```
get colorForms() {
    return this.userForms.get('colors') as FormArray
}
```

won't work since `userForms` returns `FormArray` and you have to specify index to get `colors` control which belongs to specific user.

So it might look like:

```
getColors(index) {
  return this.userForms.get([index, 'colors']) as FormArray;
}
```

and in html:

```
<div *ngFor="let color of getColors(i).controls;...>
```

Also you need to keep it in mind when working with `colors` array:

```
addColor(index: number) {
  const colorGroup = this.fb.group({
    color: []
  })

  this.getColors(index).push(colorGroup);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
 use the them method to get correct FormArray
}

deleteColor(userIndex: number, colorIndex: number) {
  this.getColors(userIndex).removeAt(colorIndex);
}
```

See also **[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/NK7zPNawxUJD7QeKQEfu)**

Comment: Works like a charm. I knew I needed to refer to the color index somehow, but I didn't know how to do it! Wonderful! Thank you!